# Bitwise operation to get the weekday name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, datetime, bitwise

The function `days_name` receive a `val` (string) corresponding to weekdays in hexadecimal.

```
def days_name(val)
    value = val.to_i(16)
    week = Array.new

    if value.eql? 127
      week.push 'All'
    elsif value.eql? 0
      week.push 'No'
    else
      week.push 'mon' if (value & 1) > 0
      week.push 'tue' if (value & 2) > 0
      week.push 'wed' if (value & 4) > 0
      week.push 'thu' if (value & 8) > 0
      week.push 'fri' if (value & 16) > 0
      week.push 'sar' if (value & 32) > 0
      week.push 'sun' if (value & 64) > 0
    end
    week.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `days_name`? Shouldn't that rather be `day_names`? Actually, given its function it should probably be `weekdays`
- Shouldn't "sar" be "sat" for Saturday? Never seen it abbreviated "sar"
- The opposite of "all" is "none" - not "no"
- Day names are capitalized in English, so "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", etc.
- You rarely need to create an array and then push items to it. It's easier to simply filter a complete array. But if you do need to create an empty array, just use `[]` - no need for `Array.new`

Sticking close to your current code, I'd do this

```
def weekdays(hex)
  value = hex.to_i(16)
  case value
  when 127
    'All'
  when 0
    'None'
  else
    days = %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)
    days.each_with_index.select { |_, i| value & 2**i > 0 }.map(&:first).join(" ")
  end
end
```

However, I'd probably prefer a method that simply returns an array of day names, rather than a string. Then let other code check and join the array as needed.

Something like this

```
def weekdays(hex)
  value = hex.to_i(16)
  days = %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)
  days.each_with_index.select { |_, i| value & 2**i > 0 }.map(&:first)
end
```

---

Update: As tokland points out in the comments, it'd be cleaner to use `map.with_index` plus `compact`, rather than `each_with_index.select` plus `map`. I.e.

```
def weekdays(hex)
  value = hex.to_i(16)
  days = %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)
  days.map.with_index { |day, i| day if value & 2**i > 0 }.compact
end
```

or, for the first code block

```
def weekdays(hex)
  value = hex.to_i(16)
  case value
  when 127
    'All'
  when 0
    'None'
  else
    days = %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)
    days.map.with_index { |day, i| day if value & 2**i > 0 }.compact.join(" ")
  end
end
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, I happened to make [a gem for weekday bitmasks](https://github.com/Flambino/week_sauce) a while back, which you might find useful. The major difference is that the gem expects Sunday to be zero, Monday to be 1 and so forth (like `Date#wday` and most other date APIs).

Comment: Nitpick: I'd prefer to write the list-comprehensions like this: `days.map.with_index { |day, i| day if value & 2**i > 0 }.compact`.

Comment: @tokland Better - certainly better. I'll update the answer an addendum

Comment: Very good answer. +1. Two ways that do not convert to an array and back: `7.times.with_object('') { |i,s| s << "#{days[i]} " if value & 2**i > 0 }.rstrip` and, without an index, `''.tap { |s| days.each { |d| s << "#{d} " if value & 1 > 0; value = value >> 1 } }.rstrip`